# Match initials from name string ignoring titles using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the initials of a name string but the string could contain a title which I want to ignore and have multiple or single names. How can I do this only using Regex in Javascript?

I can match the first character of the words in the string with `\b(\w)` but I want to ignore 'Mr' and 'Mrs' etc.
Something like.. `[^mr]\b(\w)` but this picks up the M in mr and whitespace in front and doesn't ignore any of the other titles

Example strings and matches:

```
'Mr Bob Smith' -> BS
'Miss Jessica Blue' -> JB
'tim white' -> TW
'dr Lisa S pink' -> LS
'lord Lee Kensington-Smithe' -> LK
```

Comment: You want "dr Lisa S pink" to give you LS, not LSP or LP?

Comment: Why is `tim white` TW?

Comment: You can use neagtive look ahead, like this (?!Mr|Miss|dr|lord)\b(\w)

Comment: `LSP` would be acceptable for `dr Lisa S pink`

Comment: No, I meant `dr Lisa S pink` must be `LS`, sorry

Comment: Because Pink isn't capitalized? Or because you only want the first two names, regardless? What if there is Jr, III, etc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this using negative lookahead and positive look behind.
You can try this:

```js
function firstChars(str) {
 const regex = /(?!\bmr\.?\b|\bmiss\b|\blord\b|\bdr\b)((?<=\s)|(?<=^))(\b[a-z])/ig;
 const matches = [...str.match(regex)];
 
 return matches.map(char => char.toUpperCase()).join('');
}

console.log(firstChars('Mr Bob Smith'));
console.log(firstChars('Miss Jessica Blue'));
console.log(firstChars('tim white'));
console.log(firstChars('dr Lisa S pink'));
console.log(firstChars('Drone Picker'));
console.log(firstChars('lord Lee Kensington-Smithe'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: @C0deJack, try this.

Comment: Yeah I think this will be the closest to what I need. Thanks @Sajeeb Ahamed

Comment: @C0deJack, You also can add an optional dot(.) with mr, miss etc. like ```(mr\.?|miss\.?)```

Answer (score 0):

If LSP is acceptable and the upper and lowercase variant of the titles, you could use

```
let pattern = /\b(?:(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)? )?(\w+(?:[ -]\w+)*)\b/i;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QlMyz5/1)

```js
let pattern = /\b(?:(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)? )?(\w+(?:[ -]\w+)*)\b/i;
let strings = [
  "Mr Bob Smith",
  "Miss Jessica Blue",
  "tim white",
  "dr Lisa S pink",
  "lord Lee Kensington-Smithe"
];

strings.forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(pattern);

  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1].split(" ").map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()).join(""));
  }
});
```

If you want to match only lower case or upper case for the names, you could use an alternation. For the titles you could also use an alternation which could be optional.

```
\b(?:(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)? )?((?:[A-Z]\w*(?:[ -][A-Z]\w*)*|[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)))\b
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)?`  Match any of the alternatives
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[A-Z]\w*(?:[ -][A-Z]\w*)*` Match parts starting with an uppercase
    - `|` Or
    - `[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)` Match only lowercase parts
  - `)` Close group
- `)` Close group
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SYEHku/1)

```js
let pattern = /\b(?:(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)? )?((?:[A-Z]\w*(?:[ -][A-Z]\w*)*|[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)))\b/;
let strings = [
  "Mr Bob Smith",
  "Miss Jessica Blue",
  "tim white",
  "dr Lisa S pink",
  "lord Lee Kensington-Smithe"
];

strings.forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(pattern);

  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1].split(" ").map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase()).join(""));
  }
});
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but the regex will fail upon abbreviated middle initials. See [demo on Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/ZOJCkt/3).

Comment: @collapsar I can come up with a lot of names and edge cases where it will not match :-) but that is the thing when matching names.

Comment: Middle initials are hardly an edge case, especially not in contexts where you would spell out titles :-)

Comment: @collapsar You could match an optional dot https://ideone.com/3j4SzK and `William R. Burroughs III.` would become `WRBI`

Comment: Right, that fits unless William R. Burroughs III. and William R. Burroughs II. appear in the same set of data - I readily concede that this is becoming esoteric ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer multiple steps instead of hard to parse regexes.

```
# Ignore case
name = "Mr. Frank Smith".lower()

# Get rid of the title 
name = re.sub("^(lord|mrs|mr)[.]? ","", name)

# get each first letter
name_list = name.split(" ")
for n in name_list:
    # might need to exclude III, Jr. etc.
    initials += n[0].upper()
```

From your examples, it's not clear whether you also want middle names or just first two names. Depending on what you want, you can, for example, use the below line instead of the for loop:

```
# only first and second name, even if exclude last name
initials = name_list[0][0].upper() + name_list[1][0].upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is more javascript oriented approach:

```
var initials = fullNames.map(fullname => {
    return fullname
        .replace(/^(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)\.? ?/, '') // remove title
        .split(' ')
        .map(substring => substring[0].toUpperCase())
        .join('')
        .substring(0, 2) // this part is to match only 2 chars
});
// => [ 'BS', 'JB', 'TW', 'LS', 'LK' ]
```

You can remove the `.substring(0, 2)` part if you are ok with `'dr Lisa S pink' === LSP`

```js
const fullNames = [
    "Mr Bob Smith",
    "Miss Jessica Blue",
    "tim white",
    "dr Lisa S pink",
    "lord Lee Kensington-Smithe"
]

const initials = fullNames.map(fullname => {
    return fullname
        .replace(/^(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)\.? ?/, '')
        .split(' ')
        .map(substring => substring[0].toUpperCase())
        .join('')
        .substring(0, 2)
})
const initialsV2 = fullNames.map(fullname => {
    return fullname
        .replace(/^(?:Mr|Miss|dr|lord)\.? ?/, '')
        .split(' ')
        .map(substring => substring[0].toUpperCase())
        .join('')
})
$('#initials').html(fullNames.map( (fullName, i) => `${fullName.padEnd(28, ' ')} => ${initials[i]}` ).join('\n'))

$('#initials2').html(fullNames.map( (fullName, i) => `${fullName.padEnd(28, ' ')} => ${initialsV2[i]}` ).join('\n'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<h2>V1 only 2 letters</h2>
<div id='initials'></div>
<h2>V2 any letters length</h2>
<div id='initials2'></div>
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
(\w)\w+ (\w)\w+$
```

Comment: So you never encounter names like `William R. Burroughs III.` ?